# Fixing the error: NAs introduced by coercionError in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

Tags: r, excel, debugging

I am very new to R and for an assignment I am trying to run a simple R script on an .Rmd file in studio.
The code is:

```
library(readxl)
cons<-read_xls("consump.xls")
reg1 <- dynlm(gc ~ L(gc) + L(gc, 2) + L(gc, 3), data = cons)
```

I have checked and tried debugging but I cannot seem to find what is wrong with the code, and have moved to check the consump.xls file to see if there is anything in the data that might be causing the bug but I honestly cannot find anything wrong and cannot fix this error to save my life. The data set is:
[image]

I have made sure to set the working directory to where the .Rmd file is and where the consump.xls file above is so the code has no problem assigning the file to cons.

The console output is this:

```
library(readxl)
cons<-read_xls("consump.xls")
reg1 <- dynlm(gc ~ L(gc) + L(gc, 2) + L(gc, 3), data = cons)
Warning: NAs introduced by coercionError in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

Would anyone know how to fix this error?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :')

Comment: it may be related to the "." cells, especially in the "gc" column. what represent the "." ? If its 0, switch it for 0.